# Creating multiple objects from a post array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm doing a small project to learn RoR and am stuck on a problem. I want to send a JSON array with objects to a POST request and create an object for each of the array elements, while also only permitting a set of parameters. Here's what it looks like in code:

```
class BodyPartsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :check_admin_rights, only: [:create]

  def create    
    BodyPart.create!(body_parts_params)
    json_response(BodyPart.all)
  end

  def index 
    json_response(BodyPart.all)
  end

  private 

    def body_parts_params
      params.permit(:name, :image_url)
    end
end
```

This is a sample request body:

```
[
    {
        "name" : "Abs",
        "image_url" : ""
    },
    {
        "name" : "Arms",
        "image_url" : ""
    }
]
```

The issue is how to setup `body_parts_params` so that I can only permit `name` and `image_url`. I know I can do something like:

```
  def create    
    params.each do |body_part| 
      BodyPart.create!(name: body_part[:name], image_url: body_part[:image_url])
    end
    json_response(BodyPart.all)
  end
```

but as I said, I want to make sure only the two parameters are permitted. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Why do you want to whitelist `params`? You are already cherry-picking them to create your objects. Whitelisting will make no difference.

Comment: If you want to reject requests with parameters you don't want that's a whole different beast. You should read up on the Rails API if that is what's you're after.

Comment: Read about `strong parameters`